# Why can git push fail non-fast forward following git pull?

Tags: git

I got this error and now I'm scared.

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
$ git push
To git@github.com:Unroll-Me/unrollme_thumbnail_generator.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Comment: What branch are you on? (First line of `git status` output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are not on branch `master`? `git pull` only merges the current branch.

Try

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git push
```

Comment: D'oh, I thought I confirmed that like 7 times but guess not.